# understanding box model

Tags: html, css

I thought I was understanding box model until I started a new project. Here is a stripped down example.
Whats happening is below the menu is where the content div sits. When I set #content margin-top:40px it doesn't shift down 40px. In firebug I can see that its adding the margin but its showing the margin in yellow move up into the menu area. I presumed by adding margin of 40px it would push the content div down from the menu by 40px. It works if I add padding but not margin. Is there something I'm not getting about the box model.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Home</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header"></div> <!-- Header  Ends -->
        <div id="menu">
        </div> <!-- Menu  Ends -->

        <div id="content">
            <div id="leftColumn">
                <h2>Main title</h2>
                <h3>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium</h3>
                <p>voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.</p>
            </div>
            <div id="centerColumn"></div>
            <div id="rightColumn"></div>
        </div>

     </div> <!-- Wrapper Ends -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not seeing the behaviour you're describing. Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wxENw/

Comment: Thanks @Matthew Lehner yea seems to work correctly in jsfiddle. Maybe I have a float in one of the other containers thats messing it up. I added float:left to the #content element as @catfish suggested and now it works as should.

Comment: Adding floats should be a last ditch effort. They take the object out of the document 'flow' and are generally not best practice. If the page layout becomes more complex, you'll run into issues. Instead, I'd recommend you use the following reset methods: `overflow:auto;` or `clear:both;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure if you add a float to #content, it should move down 40px, but I didn't test it.

Comment: you mean add float:left. Doesn't that mean it will float to the left which means that it will sit beside the menu not below it.

Comment: give it a try and see. you can always specify a width for #content and then add `margin: 0 auto;` to #content

Comment: When I set a width on my wrapper then it floated below it. I only use float for floating divs beside each other. I didn't know you had to also set float for a div below a div. If thats the case I need to set every element to float?

Comment: Usually just the parent element of whatever you want floated.

Answer (score 0):

If padding is working better than margin, it won't do much harm to use that instead.

I saw this behavior in your example markup until I added a little text inside `<div id="menu">` so as to make it not empty, and then margin worked exactly as expected.

Another possible workaround is to set a minimum height on the div's, though I haven't tested that.